# How to get response from https server having certificates exception in android?

Tags: android, ssl, https

My website has address https://blablabla.com (not actual one). It does not have the approved certificates from CA. So, any user accessing the website gets a certificate exception(on the browser); this exception he/she has to add to the browser and then the website starts to work on the browser.

I have the following:

- A server configured to establish a HTTPS connection, and require a client certificate.
- This server has a certificate that is not issued by a standard large-scale CA. In short, if I access this connection via the browser in Android, it throws an exception because the devices truststore doesnt recognizes the CA. (So it's  self-signed)
- A client certificate that is essentially self-signed.
- An Android app that loads this self-signed certificate and attempts to connect to the aforementioned server, but has the following problems/properties:

The client can connect to the server when the server is configured to not require a client certificate. The connection works fine, however I get no response on android.

I have written some APIs and uploaded them on the server. I want to get the result on the mobile when I call the API from the mobile-side on the mobile. However, I get no response from the server;I think I am missing something. Heres what I did.. Please help me out.

```
    private static final HostnameVerifier DUMMY_VERIFIER = new HostnameVerifier() {

    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {

        return true;
    }
};

    public static String method(String url)
        throws Exception {

    // Trust manager to accept all certificates..
    TrustManager localTrustManager = new X509TrustManager() {

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                String authType) throws CertificateException {

        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                String authType) throws CertificateException {

        }

    };

    HttpsURLConnection con = null;

    try {
        // URL object is built..
        URL urlObj = new URL(url);

        SSLContext sslc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        sslc.init(null, new TrustManager[] { localTrustManager },
                new SecureRandom());

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslc
                .getSocketFactory());

        // Connection is established..
        con = (HttpsURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
        con.setHostnameVerifier(DUMMY_VERIFIER);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        con.setUseCaches(false);
        con.setDoOutput(true);

        DataOutputStream writer_stream = new DataOutputStream(
                con.getOutputStream());

        // for sending info to server..
        writer_stream.writeBytes(new_request);
        writer_stream.flush();
        writer_stream.close();

        // Get Response from the server..
        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();

        return response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    } finally {

        if (con != null) {
            con.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done in the onCreate method of the MainActivity

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new NullHostNameVerifier());
        try {
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            TrustManager[] tm = new TrustManager[] {
                    new X509TrustManager() {

                        @Override
                        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
                            // not implemented
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
                            // not implemented
                        }

                        @Override
                        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return null;
                        }

                    }
            };
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

        }catch(Exception e){}
```

Comment: I have created a separate class which handles the web-service and the https part. (So much for not messing up the android code).